# Is it possible to transfer MS SQL results to a new MS Excel file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am transferring SQL results to an existing Excel file using below query. Is it possible to transfer them to a new excel sheet? Using SSIS we can do this, but I want to know whether there is any possibility to do in SSMS.

```
SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

SP_CONFIGURE 'Database Mail XPs', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1   

INSERT INTO OPENROWSET 
   ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
   'Excel 8.0;Database=E:\LessThan1300\OutofScope.xlsx;','select * from [Sheet1$]')
   select * from tboutofscope 
   where InflowDate >= CONVERT(date,getdate())
```

Comment: Your query is fine as far as I can tell. Are you getting any errors here? Is your sheet named Sheet1 in the file? Is it on the E: drive of the SQL server or do you need a network path? Are you trying to create a new sheet with the query?

Comment: This query works fine if I have an existing worksheet. I want to do the same to a new excel file.

Comment: Is this an ongoing excel report? Have you thought about using power query?

Comment: You wish to create new xlsx file first, or you have an xlsx file and wish to put your data on a new sheet?

Comment: If you need a new file you can try with bcp instead.

Comment: @Isaiah3015, How to use a power query?

Comment: @PavelBotygin, I want to create new xlsx inside SSMS using SQL query

Comment: @JacobH, How can I use bcp?

Comment: @OP, Power query when you have an Excel file that you can connect to the database and grab the results. This is easier to use if that same report is utilized daily, all you have to do is refresh it and it pulls the data back to Excel. Here's a tutorial on how to build it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVgXcTy0kM0

Comment: @Madhukar, why don't you use a template xlsx file? Then you could copy it to your "new" xlsx, and fill it with your data.

Comment: @PavelBotygin, you mean writing data on a template file and saving it as a new file? Is yes, then how can I do this in SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create copy of your template file like this:

```
DECLARE @sqlscript VARCHAR(4000), @pathtotemplatefile VARCHAR(MAX) = 'E:\LessThan1300\template.xlsx', @pathtonewfile VARCHAR(MAX) = 'E:\LessThan1300\OutofScope.xlsx', @xlsxdatabase varchar(4000)
--SET @pathtotemplatefile = 'c:\i\1.xlsx'
--SET @pathtonewfile = 'c:\i\2.xlsx'
SET @sqlscript='copy ' + @pathtotemplatefile + ' ' + @pathtonewfile
EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @sqlscript, no_output

set @xlsxdatabase = 'Excel 8.0;Database=' + @pathtonewfile + ';'

INSERT INTO OPENROWSET 
   ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', @xlsxdatabase,'select * from [Sheet1$]')
   select * from tboutofscope 
   where InflowDate >= CONVERT(date,getdate())
```

You can dynamically change the name of the new file according to your needs, "create" it and then fill it with expected data.

Comment: Thank for this. But contents of the template file is copying to the new file. I changed 'copy' to 'move', then the template is getting deleted and a new file is getting created. Any way I can just dump the query results into a new file?

Comment: You should create a new empty xlsx file as template (or take one of yours OutofScope.xlsx, remove all rows from it and name it "OutofScope_template.xlsx" ), and use (copy) it (to OutofScope.xlsx for instance) every time when you need new file for your export. Template file should persist in its location w/o changes.

Comment: I tried this. But the contents of the template file is not getting moved.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean below SQL is not deleting contents of Template file.
`INSERT INTO OPENROWSET 
   ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
   'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\POPAClause\Template.xlsx;','select * from [Sheet1$]')select top(4) * from tbLogin
 
DECLARE @sqlscript VARCHAR(4000), @pathtotemplatefile VARCHAR(MAX) = 'D:\POPAClause\Template.xlsx', @pathtonewfile VARCHAR(MAX) = 'D:\POPAClause\T3.xlsx'
SET @sqlscript='copy ' + @pathtotemplatefile + ' ' + @pathtonewfile
EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @sqlscript, no_output`

Comment: Because you are using it the wrong way. First, you should make a copy of your template. Then put your data to the made copy. `DECLARE @sqlscript VARCHAR(4000), @pathtotemplatefile VARCHAR(MAX) = 'D:\POPAClause\Template.xlsx', @pathtonewfile VARCHAR(MAX) = 'D:\POPAClause\T3.xlsx'
SET @sqlscript='copy ' + @pathtotemplatefile + ' ' + @pathtonewfile EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @sqlscript, no_output
set @xlsxdatabase = 'Excel 8.0;Database=' + @pathtonewfile + ';'
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', @xlsxdatabase,'select * from [Sheet1$]')select top(4) * from tbLogin`